# Wrong monitor resolution on startup Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, xrandr

I have a problem with my Arch Linux, (probably it was my fault, I may or may not have uninstalled something). The problem is that every time I boot up the screen resolution is set to a very low one. To solve the issue I run `killall Xorg` and it fixes itself, I don't know the reason. I am using i3 window manager and lightdm. Hope you can help me because I am a little tired of running `killall` every time I use my PC.

The output of xrandr is

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480        0.00*
```

I also noticed that when I run nvidia-smi, there aren't any running processes. Even though there must be 3 from Xorg and 1 from my terminal (kitty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different things I solved the problem by running `sudo nvidia-xconfig`, I also reinstalled Xorg, but I think the configuration file solved it.